# Awk to get all my regular users in shadow

Tags: bash, scripts

I have a script.

I want to get all my regular users from `/etc/shadow` e.g all users which second term in shadow file begins with `$` or `!$`.

My pattern is

```
sudo getent shadow | awk -F: '$2 ~ /^$/ || /^!$/ {print $1}'
```

It doesn't work for now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to escape the `$`, as it is a special char for "End of Line" much like `^` is "Beginning of Line".

```
sudo getent shadow | awk -F: '$2 ~ /^\$/ || $2 ~  /^!\$/ {print $1}'
```

Comment: Simplified: `awk -F: '$2 ~ /^!?\$/ {print $1}'` - This combines the two match tests and says "match a dollar sign at the beginning of the field, optionally (`?`) preceded by a `!`"

Answer (score 4):

All users with a password set can be listed like this:

```
getent shadow | egrep '^[^:]*:[*!]:' -v | cut -f1 -d:
```